# How validate array of id?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, php-7

I get string which I can convert to array.

All elements of array is id of entity. I need validate if all id of entity is exists?

How it realize in Laravel request?

Comment: Your code - show it to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [create a custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules) and use `whereIn()` and `count()`:

```
$count = Model::whereIn('id', $array)->count();
if ($count === count($array))
```